# Why is free-jqgrid not resetting row ids after GridUnload?

Tags: jqgrid

### The Problem

I have a very complex, rather outdated jqgrid implementation that I'm upgrading to the latest free-jqgrid and we're having an issue in that after clearing the grid with unload, when we re-initialize the grid, the row ids are higher than they should be to start.

They seem to still be incrementing and not starting again. Are there some global counters I need to clear out to have the grid completely clear itself before we re-render it?

### Grid Clear

```
        if ( this.timesheet_grid ) {
            this.timesheet_grid.grid.jqGrid( 'GridUnload' );
            this.timesheet_grid.grid = null;
            this.timesheet_grid = null;
```

### Rows after GridUnload has been run

Shows an id like `jqg56`

### Stuff I've Tried Since Posting

- GridDestroy
- clearGridBeforeUnload

### SOLUTION

As @Oleg has suggested i simply needed to set the id attribute manually when processing the grid data.

Comment: see github issue here: https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your incorrectly understand the meaning of rowids and the requirements for input data. I'm wonder especially about the suggestion of Tony to reset `$.jgrid.guid`. I find the suggestion **very bad** because it looks like a solution, but it can produce more seriously problems as the problems, which are solved!

First of all, it's important to understand *what is rowid*. Rowid is the values of `id` attribute of the grid rows: the `id` values of `<tr>` elements of the grid's body (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div)). The rowid are used as a parameter of almost all callbacks and events of jqGrid. Because of that jqGrid **must** assign id attribute to every row and the input data of the grid **have to** contain rowid information! The existence of rowids is critical for working jqGrid. Only because of that jqGrid *generates* unique rowids *in case of wrong input data*. Alternative for generation of ids would be preventing creating the grid at all.

jqGrid tolerates the error with specifying the rowids in input data only for some simple grids, where one need just display some simple data and one never need to use rowids. If you use ids then you should fix the problem only in one way: **you have to fix your input data**. You can for example include `id` property with unique value in every element of input data. You should take in consideration that no id duplicates exist not only in the grid but on the *whole HTML page*. It's strictly recommended to use `idPrefix` option with unique value for every grid always if your HTML page have more as one grids (inclusive grid with subgrids).

Resetting of `$.jgrid.guid` is **very dangerous** and it can break functionality of jqGrid because of creating elements with duplicate id values. The property `$.jgrid.guid` is **global**. It's common over all grids and subgrids on the page. Simple subgrids scenario will produces id duplicates after you manually reset `$.jgrid.guid`. It will be used inside of `$.jgrid.randId()` method used in *many* places of jqGrid code. For example, the method `addRow` used by `inlineNav` uses the method.

I repeat my suggestion more clear once more. If you uses rowids or if the values of rowids are important for you in some way then you have to include `id` property to every item of input data. If some other property has already an unique value then you can add `key: true` in the corresponding column of `colModel` (one can use `key: true` in only one column). Alternatively, you can add `prmNames: { id: "myId" }` if `myId` property of input data contains unique rowid instead of default `id` property.

Comment: The system uses uuids, is that why it's creating the ever-higher ids?

Comment: @catbadger: Could you explain more clear what you mean? I can't understand you because you didn't posted your code. I have no idea which `datatype` you use, whether you use simple jqGrid, jqGrid with groping, subgrids, TreeGrid and so on. Which format have the input data for the grid and which `colModel` you use? I can't help you if we discuss the problem on the same level of details.

Comment: I think i misunderstood your post when I commented. So the row ids which do not always start with jqg1 after the grid is wiped then re-instated can't be made to line up with my parallel data array that I do not want to store in the grid? The old jqgrid supported this, and we do a lot of custom stuff in a page with 5-10 grids depending on state information. We need each grid to have it's own set of row ids that allow us to parrallel that information with the very specific json that we are using. This means that the rowids must be ordinal and start at 1 in each grid.

Comment: @catbadger: I think we speak about different things. Could you answer on my question: how you fill the data in the grid? If you want to have the same ids for the rows after reloading then you should just *set* the values which you want to have as `id` property. You can set `id` of the client or on the server side. I can't suggest you more because I have no idea about which kind of grid you use and in which way you create it and fill the data in the grid, whether you display data or edit it, whether you use local/remote paging/searching/filtering or not.

Comment: @catbadger: You didn't wrote which version of jqGrid you use now, from which fork of jqGrid and which "old jqgrid" version you mean. Very old version assigned ids like `rowIndex`: 1, 2, 3... The values changed on sorting (if the user clicks on the column header) for example.

Comment: yes we are upgrading from the original (prefork) jqGrid. My server's id fields are strings. They are UUIDs.

Comment: @catbadger: If one column of your input data contains UUID than you can just add `prmNames: { id: "theUuidColumnName" }` or/and to include `key: true` property for the column in `colModel`. After that the rowids will be the UUIDs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160107/discussion-between-catbadger-and-oleg).

Answer (score 2):

jqGrid uses common counter in order to be a sure that there will be no duplicate values when a build in id generator is used.

To reset the value you will need to set the guid parameter to 1 - i.e

```
$.jgrid.guid =1;
```

after you unload the grid

Comment: This was a big help. Thank you, @Tony I'm definitely going to need to work that into my wrapper class.

Comment: So all grids are using the same counter? ooh that's going to cause some refactoring...

Comment: The variable is stored in the common $.jgrid object which is loaded when grid file is loaded.

Comment: If you need to do a lot of work regarding this I suggest you to overwrite the randId function to meet your requirements. the function is defined as: `...randId : function( prefix ) {
  return (prefix || $.jgrid.uidPref) + ($.jgrid.guid++);
},` . so you can easy add a code `$.jgrid.randId = function(){...}` after you load the grid file

Answer (score 1):

If the solution is based on the knowing the behavior of the product, then this is a good solution.

If we try to solve the problem, without to knowing  the behavior - it is a dangerous solution.

It is very easy to say - **this is bad solution and it is very very dangerous to use this solution** - so my question is:

What is happen with the counter if the user reload the page under some conditions?

The answer is:  the counter is reset and we go to the same situations which are described in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the rows you can use `$.jgrid.guid-rows` to get the ids as if they are reset.

```
 var rows = $("#gridtable").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     var reset = rows[i]-($.jgrid.guid-rows.length - 1)
  });
```